# Way to set div's height to fit in remaining space

Tags: html, css, height

I tried to make div have rest of unused space in height. My design consits of header (50 pixels), footer (40 pixels) and content which i want to get remaining space. I'm using `calc` function at the moment, but i heard it is rather slow and i shouldn't use it too much.

https://jsfiddle.net/md9cb24u/ The `main-wrapper` doesn't work for some reason in jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you prodive your entire code on jsfiddle in order to help you ?

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the page in `.main-box` and update css part

You can get the same with `flex` properties

```
.main-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
/* TAGS */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* END OF TAGS */


/* WRAPPERS */

#wrapper-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: url("background.png");
}

#wrapper-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - (90px));
  background-color: green;
}

#wrapper-footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}


/* END OF WRAPPERS */


/* CONTENT */

#menu {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  width: 23%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #3B3B3B;
  float: left;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-right: 2%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'codropsicons', verdana;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-a:hover,
.menu-active {
  background-color: #FAA732;
}

.menu-a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.menu-li {
  text-align: center;
}


/* END OF CONTENT*/


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {}


/* END OF MEDIA QUERIES */


/* FONTS */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'codropsicons';
  src: url('codropsicons.tff');
}


/* END OF FONTS */
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="main-box">
    <div id="wrapper-header">
      <ul id="menu">
        <a class="menu-a menu-active" href="#">
          <li class="menu-li">O nas</li>
        </a>
        <a class="menu-a" href="#">
          <li class="menu-li">Oferta</li>
        </a>
        <a class="menu-a" href="#">
          <li class="menu-li">Galeria</li>
        </a>
        <a class="menu-a" href="#">
          <li class="menu-li">Kontakt</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper-main">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto illo, consequuntur odit illum est! Tenetur incidunt cumque, laborum delectus non numquam est placeat, animi sed temporibus, dignissimos voluptate eius quidem.
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper-footer">

    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```